# How to get 'Authorization' Header in Angular 5

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt

I have Spring-Boot JWT enabled REST APIs. Authentication API /login does provide All the CORS and AUTH headers as expected. Tested with Curl and Postman.
My Client code is in Angular 5. When successfully authenticated I can see -

1. All the required headers, specifically 'Authorization' header in Developer Tools of Chrome in Network Traffic.
2. However when accessed with Angular 5 HttpClient no Header is accessible in Component/Service.

Note: Backend side, CORS and Allow Headers is enabled, and hence Chrome Network Traffic is fine.

Added the required options in HttpClient during POST call.

```
{
     responseType: 'text',
     observe: 'response'
}
```

Tried with all possible responseType there.
JSON, as default, throws Parse Exceptions.
It means the default Spring-Boot JWTS /login API does not return JSON Output but returns only HttpResponse.

Please help...

Angular Code -

```js
login(payload: any): Observable < any > {

    return this._http.post(this.loginEndPoint, payload, {
        responseType: 'text',
        observe: 'response'
    })
        /* .map((response: HttpResponse<string>) => {
            console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization'));
            return response;
        }); */
        .pipe(
        tap(response => {
            console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization'));
            return response;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
        );
}
```

Comment: Hello, I was bit late on this. More confusing was the thing that i was able to get the Headers in Postman and in Chrome Developer Console but not in Angular.
Initially i thought it is because of Angular OR Observable OR XMLHttpRequest that Angular uses internally.
The thing is simple just to add

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");

I was also trying with following which did not work

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept, x-requested-with, Cache-Control");

Thanks, I hope it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

The `tap` operator does not emit values in the observable stream. So returning something in it will not do anything. It is used to do side effect things like logging. To emit a value use the `map` operator

```
.pipe(
    map(response => {
       return response.headers.get('Authorization');
   })
)
```

Note: This only returns the header to the component that subscribed.

Comment: thanks @LLai, I tried using Map independently without pipe actually. Here also it is **not working**. I do not need complete response as such. Only header, which i need to store is required. Hence i can either return specific Header or complete Response..

Comment: @Prafulla maybe this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43010215/7176268) answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a line in your backend:
response.addHeader("access-control-expose-headers", "Authorization");

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.