# Angular 5 HTTP Client has "Authorization" missing from the Response header

Tags: angular, http, jwt

I am working with JWT (JSON Web Tokens) as a part of logging people into the system. The code that does this is as follows:

```
this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }), { observe: 'response' })
      .subscribe((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
```

When sending the `username` and `password` to the server, the Response object contains the encrypted authorization in the Header.

Included as part of the headers is an `Authorization` entry and also a `Pragma` entry. The `Authorization` has the token correctly defined (and it works). `Pragma` is also defined as `no-cache`

From Network tab in Chrome:

[image]

but when running the code to process the response headers, the `Authorization` header is not present.

```
 adminLogin(username, password) {
    let url = `${this._apiRoot}/login`;
    let tokenResp = {};

    this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }), { observe: 'response' })
      .subscribe((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {

        console.log(" ---- begin response ----");
        console.log( response );
        console.log(" ---- end response ----");

        let token = response.headers.get("Authorization");

        console.log(" ---- begin token ----");
        console.log ( token );
        console.log(" ---- end token ----");

        let pragma = response.headers.get("pragma");

        console.log(" ---- begin pragma ----");
        console.log ( pragma );
        console.log(" ---- end pragma ----");
```

Results from code executed:

[image]

From the code executed, one can see that the trying to find the `Authorization` returns `null` while `Pragma` gets `no-cache`. What is going on?

**UPDATE**

Thanks all for the information.

I followed the information here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13554

and made changes to the java code:

```
@Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String username = ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        ApplicationUser user = applicationUserRepository
                .findByUsername(username);

        String token = Jwts
                .builder()
                .setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .claim("id", user.getId())

            [... snip ...]

            res.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
            res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING,SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);

    }
```

Thanks again!

Comment: That header isn't allowed to be exposed to the code, you need to set `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43010215/3001761

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20554. You must allow the headers using `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

Comment: Also note you don't have to `JSON.stringify` the body yourself, and you can use object shorthand notation to write e.g. `{ username, password }`. Another related Q: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42306684/3001761

Comment: you can post your "update" as an answer. Make it easyer for other people to see it

Comment: Suppose I don't want to expose headers. How am I supposed to store the token on the client side or send authenticated requests if the token came in on an `Authorization` header?

Answer (score 4):

To solve this issue we need to expose the desired header from the backend side and use and write a custom [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

**NodeJs API exemple**: Expose `authorization` header from backend

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'authorization'); 
res.setHeader('authorization', 'foo-bar');
```

**Sample angular interceptor**

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        if (response.headers) {
          console.log('Header keys', response.headers.keys());
          console.log('Authorization: ', response.headers.get('authorization'));
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Lastly we add our interceptor to our module providers

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpInterceptorService } from './http-interceptor.service';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpInterceptorService, multi: true },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/github/melcor76/interceptors) and [repos can](https://github.com/melcor76/interceptors) be usefull to know more about Angular HttpInterceptor

Answer (score -1):

```
const options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        })
    };
    const requestPayload = ({
        user_type: userType
    });
    return this.http.post<UserModel>(`${API_BASE_URL}/user/${uid}`, JSON.stringify(requestPayload), options);
```

the above should work fine if you don't want to use the interceptor method, do not that for a post method needs 3 arguments to work in this case: endpoiontURL | requestBody | headerOptions

Comment: this doesn't answer the question about how to read the token from the http response