# Unable to access authorization headers from HTTP response

Tags: angular, rest, spring-security, jwt, angular-httpclient

I'm having following piece of code

```
authenticate(username: string, password: string) {
    this.callAuthenticationEndpoint(username, password).subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp.headers)
      console.log(resp.headers.get('Authorization'))
    })
  }

  callAuthenticationEndpoint(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    var url = this.AUTHENTICATE_URL + 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
    var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers, observe: "response"});
  }
```

That calls backend I wrote using Spring. I'v tested it before integrating with Angular so I'm sure it works. Also, when I call methods above, I got this in Chrome

[image]

But for some reason, I can't access this data in code..

[image]

Comment: Which HttpModule ur using?

Comment: '@angular/common/http'

Comment: Try changing the observable `Observable<HttpResponse<any>>`

Comment: Still same result after changing to `Observable<HttpResponse<any>>`

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968674/angular-6-get-response-headers-with-httpclient-issue?rq=1

Comment: Seems this should help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777244/angular-5-http-client-has-authorization-missing-from-the-response-header

Comment: Thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968674/angular-6-get-response-headers-with-httpclient-issue?rq=1 worked