# Angular HTTPResponse header Authorization is null

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt, http-headers

I am trying to get the authentication token from the login response but the value is null and I think that only Content-Type attribute is not null...

Login method

```js
login(credentials: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + '/login', {
      username: credentials.username, 
      password: credentials.password
    }, {observe: 'response'});
  }
```

```js
this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value)
      .subscribe((res:Response) => {
        console.log(res.headers.get('Authorization'));
    },
    err => {
      this.isLoginError = true;
      this.loginErrorMessage = err.error;
    });
```

[image: Response headers]

**EDIT:**

I added `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` to my backend response and it works.

```java
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
            response.addHeader("Authorization", jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(auth));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you have to add "**Access-Control-Expose-Headers**" to the response headers in your backend side.

Response from
[Angular 5 HTTP Client has "Authorization" missing from the Response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777244/angular-5-http-client-has-authorization-missing-from-the-response-header)